# Порядок байтов при чтении файла

Tags: c++, файлы, байты, порядок

Почему при чтении бинарного файла нет опции для указания порядка байтов? Есть только `binary` режим, но нет `LE` или `BE`.

Как `>>` узнаёт порядок байтов файла? Как узнать его программно?

Comment: Вообще-то файл - это последовательность *байтов*, и не более того. А не `int`ов, скажем, для которых это имело бы значение...

Comment: @Harry так как узнать, как инт прочитать?

Comment: Использовать текстовый файл :) Или оговаривать формат бинарного файла (по сути, сериализацию) заранее.

Comment: @Harry дан бинарный файл с 4байтными числами (вся информация). Как прочитать эти числа, не зная его порядок байтов? Понятно, что можно посмотреть его содержимое и угадать. Но почему из кода нельзя это сделать? Если можно, то как? То есть, я читаю `in >> x;`, как он определяет порядок?

Comment: используется локальный формат. Можно использовать Qt - там есть возможность задать порядок байт

Comment: @sprut, *`"То есть, я читаю in >> x;, как он определяет порядок?"`* -- никак, т.е. считается совпадающим с native для данной платформы

Comment: Вот правда интересно, по каким критериям минусуют вопрос?

Comment: @avp а на винде и линуксе этот native одинаковый? Просто файл получаю с винды, а читать хочу на линуксе. Про порядок байтов ничего не сказано, сказано только, что это куча интов 4байтных

Comment: @KoVadim можно узнать локальный формат, если файл не я создавал?

Comment: если в случае винды можно с большой вероятностью угадать платформу, то в случае с линуксом - нет. Если файл не Вы создавали и целевая платформа не известна, то можно только гадать. А что бы не нужно было гадать, умные дядьки давно придумали hton и ntoh

Comment: `in >> x` - это **текстовое** чтение, а не бинарное! Ответ: в общем случае - а никак. Этот порядок определяется тем, как создавался файл.

Comment: На практике с большой вероятностью формат LE (x86 и большинство реализаций на arm используют его)

Comment: @Harry почему тогда это компилируется, если я `std::ios_base::binary` указываю?

Comment: @Harry https://godbolt.org/z/6M6Mvd вот, например

Comment: А этот флаг говорит только об одном - **НЕ преобразовывать `\n\r` в `\n`** (в Windows, DOS, OS/2), а читать все как есть :)